# set stage variable for sam local testing

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have a few lambda functions organized with sam which use stage variables and are deployed to production like so,

```
sam deploy 
aws apigateway create-deployment --variables file://stage-vars.json
```

I want a way to test my functions locally using the same stage vars but there seems to be no why to do that. Prior to using stage variables I was using `sam local start-api` which provides no suitable options.

Has anyone found a way around this ?